# Pandas hashtable with gives key error:0

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, bigdata

I am trying to get the same elements of two pandas data table, with indexing the datas and merge it. I use it for a very large amount of data(millions). The frist table (df) is constatn, and the second(d2) is changing in every loop, with the new elements will be merged with the first table.

here is my code for this process:

```
df = pd.read_csv("inputfile.csv",header=None)
d1 = pd.DataFrame(df).set_index(0) 

for i in range(0, len(df)):
    try:
            follower_id=twitter.get_followers_ids(user_id=df.iloc[i][0],cursor=next_cursor) 


            f=follower_id['ids']
            json.dumps(f)
            d2 = pd.DataFrame(f).set_index(0) 
            match_result = pd.merge(d1,d2,left_index=True,right_index=True) 
            fk=[df.iloc[i][0] for number in range(len(match_result))] 
            DF = pd.DataFrame(fk)

            DF.to_csv(r'output1.csv',header=None,sep=' ',index=None) 
            match_result.to_csv(r'output2.csv', header=None,  sep=' ')
```

I have experienced, that this code, runs well for a while, but after that- probably it is relatad to the second databasses size wich is change every loop- the program gives me the following error message, and stop running:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "halozat3.py", line 39, in <module>
d2 = pd.DataFrame(f).set_index(0) #1Trump koveto kovetolistaja
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2372, in set_index
level = frame[col].values
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1678, in __getitem__
return self._getitem_column(key)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1685, in _getitem_column
return self._get_item_cache(key)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1052, in _get_item_cache
values = self._data.get(item)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2565, in get
loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1181, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))
File "index.pyx", line 129, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3656)
File "index.pyx", line 149, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3534)
File "hashtable.pyx", line 381, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:7035)
File "hashtable.pyx", line 387, in          pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:6976)
KeyError: 0
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Quite simply, `0` is not a column label. Have you tried `d2 = pd.DataFrame(f).set_index('ids')`?

Comment: I'd recommend catching the exception and printing f when the KeyError occurs. This way you can see how this f is different from what you expect, since it seems for some reason that this one doesn't have column 0, whilst the others do.

Comment: I tryed it, but is gives me: `KeyError: 'ids'`

Comment: can you provide the output of "f"?

Comment: I wrote an exception, but also exited, with the same error message.
Here is my exception for this:
 
              `try:`
              `pandas codes`       
              `except (ValueError,TypeError,IndexError) as er:`
                       `print er.error_code`
                       `print f`



what is wrong with this @Skirrebattie?

Comment: try putting this in your code at the right place (instead of just d2 = pd.DataFrame(f).set_index(0)):
try: 
    d2 = pd.DataFrame(f).set_index(0) 
except KeyError:
    print(f)
then you can see f and where it is going wrong

Comment: It printed:  [ ] can it caused a problem with the empty table, yes?
Should i put some other exceptions for the continuous streaming, or other advice? @Skirrebattie

Comment: yup seems like an empty table was the problem. This way you can just catch the exception and keep going as you planned. Does it work now? @John

Comment: yes it is working now. thank you for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you only one row in your dataframe?

You must write as many rows as you like
[Look](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)